# Cannot import MQTTUtils into Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I cannot import `MQTTUtils` in my Python project.

```
from mqtt import MQTTUtils
```

I installed `mqtt` and `paho-mqtt`:

```
pip install mqtt
pip install paho-mqtt
pip3 install mqtt
pip3 install paho-mqtt
```

... but still the compiler says "Unresolved reference MQTTUtils".
Also when I run the code outside of the compiler (IntellijIDEA), it also crashes with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mqtt'".

Did I miss something?

Comment: Which compiler ? As far as I know Python code is interpreted

Comment: @Agile_Eagle. IntellijIDEA. Also when I run the code from console, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mqtt'". So, it seems that I should install something else. I did `pip install mqtt` and `pip install paho-mqtt`

Comment: Do you have 2 different versions of python

Comment: @Agile_Eagle: yes, but I executed both `pip3` and `pip` to install the libraries. Requirements are satisfied for both versions of Python.

Comment: which operating system are you using? Are you sure that it was successfully installed?

Comment: @TarunWadhwa: I am on MacOS. I was able to use `MQTTUtils` only after copying-pasting the code of `MQTTUtils` directly into the project's folder. Now it works, but it looks crappy.